# What are the possible reasons for a sudden decrease in the number of images being indexed in my sitemap?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, googlebot, lazyloading

A number of sitemaps contain URLs, and a number of those URLs contain image URLs with captions, titles, etc.

Suddenly over the past five days, there has been a drop in the number of images indexed by Google.

[image]

(It rose for a bit, then suddenly dropped.)

---

The only development on the website was implementing `lazy-load` of images, to reduce the page size.

Answer (score 1):

The way lazy loading works is that you with scripting first loads and serves the correct image source when an image is visible in the visitors viewport but googlebot won’t index these images because the correct image source isn’t rendered serversite.

TL;DR: – short story: Lazy loaded images won’t be indexed by search bots like googlebot!

Comment: Is there a work around to this?

Some pages have 60 images, but we'd like all them indexed if possible.

Comment: search engine crawlers don't execute scripts, they only analyze HTML markup, so all the code that renders images dynamically is totally ignored along with images and captions.

Comment: So in that case, there's a trade-off between page size, and the number of images indexed. Any practices that you're aware of?

Comment: general advice about this is - 'do nothing'. :) and srsly, I mean it.

Comment: Sorry, that's a little unclear, when you say `do nothing` do you mean remove the lazy load, or do you mean, keep the lazy-load and let google naturally index the first few images?

Comment: http://dinbror.dk/blog/lazy-load-images-seo-problem/

Comment: Thanks for this, just read it. So if Google will run JS and crawl these images eventually, then when(approx.) should I start seeing an increase in GWT for the number of indexed images?